# How do I delete words containing a certain charater in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, filereader, symbols

Is there a way to delete a whole word that contains the "@" character using regular expressions?

For example, the following words should be removed: `kʌn@tənɪu` and `b@ilu`

I have tried:

```
line = br.readLine();
line = line.replaceAll("\\b[@]+\\b","");
System.out.println(line);
```

... which only deletes the "@" symbol, not the word itself.

Comment: Define "word"... Also, what about spacing between "words"? Do you want to keep them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the regex

```
[^@\s]*@\S*
```

[^@\s]* looks for zero or more chars that are not a '@' or whitespace

@ looks for one '@'

\s* looks for zero or more chars that are not whitespace

so the line of code would be:

```
line = line.replaceAll("[^@\\s]*@\\s*","");
```

Comment: `.` matches any character that's not a *line terminator* (equivalent to `[^\r\n\u0085\u2028\u2029]` in Java, but other flavors define it differently).  For *non-whitespace* characters, use `\S`.

Answer (score 0):

```
line = br.readLine();
line = line.replaceAll("\\b.+?[@]+.+?\\b","");
System.out.println(line);
```

EDIT:  `.*?` was no good.  I tested the latest edit and it worked for me.

```
    String test =  "  x+1@ three@two @@ o@ne @ two";
    test = test.replaceAll("\\b.+?[@]+.+?\\b","");
    System.out.println(test);
```

Gives

```
two
```

Comment: it wont replace the '@' in the string " @ "

Comment: @deme72.  Does for me.  I just updated my answer with the new test string.

Comment: @deme72.  I see.  You mean `" @ "` only.  Agreed.  Doesn't work for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex like:

```
(\\s+)([^\\s]*?@[^\\s]*?)(\\s+)
```

If you would like to replace it with both whitespaces surrounding it, you could replace the it with `$1$3`.

If you would like to replace it with only one whitespace (this looks better), you could replace it with either `$1` or `$3`.

[Here's a preview of the regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/dI8qN3/2) on regex101.com, and here's how it works:

> `\\s` matches any whitespace character
> `\\s`**`+`** maches any whitespace character one or more times.
>
> `[^\\s]` matches any non-whitespace character
> `[^\\s]`**`*?`** matches any non-whitespace character any amount of times, and tries to find the smallest match.
>
> `@` matches the character **@** literally.
>
> `[^\\s]` matches any non-whitespace character
> `[^\\s]`**`*?`** matches any non-whitespace character any amount of times, and tries to find the smallest match.
>
> `\\s` matches any whitespace character
> `\\s`**`+`** maches any whitespace character one or more times.